# Действие при скролле

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код: когда скролл достигает определенный див, этот див появляется с анимацией. После чего, когда я уже нахожусь на этом диве и прокручиваю скролл, анимация прогресс бара срабатывает заново. Как исправить, чтобы анимация прогресс бара была только один раз при скролле к этому блоку. Надеюсь, вопрос понятен.

```
var h = $(window).height();
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ( ($(this).scrollTop()+h) >= $(".services-procent-ul").offset().top) {
            $(".op").css({visibility:"visible"});
            $(".op").addClass('animated zoomIn');
            $('.circle1').circleProgress({
                value: 0.9,
                emptyFill: "#504a3f",
                startAngle: -Math.PI/2,
                size: 110,
                animation: {duration: 6000},
                thickness: "15",
                fill: {
                    color: "#bae103"
                }
            }).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event,progress, stepValue) {
                $(this).find('strong').text(100*String(stepValue.toFixed(1))+'%');
            });
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил.

```
$(window).bind('scroll.once', function(){ 
   show_graphics(); 
});
function show_graphics() {
   //run code
   $(window).unbind('scroll.once')
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробую угадать:

```
$(window).one('scroll', function() {
```

А вообще, желательно приводить в вопросе работающий пример с разметкой.

Comment: Если находится на этом диве при обновлении страницы, то все появляется. А если скролить сверху  к блоку, то там будет пусто.

Comment: Нужно, чтобы при первом вхождении скрола на див, скрипт больше не срабатывал.

Comment: Добавить флаг(например data-attribute какой нибудь у дива), как только див появился устанавливаешь в true. Прежде чем вызвать анимацию, проверяешь наличие флага.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую